# Is there an equivalent of junit test suite in Scala

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, junit, scalatest

In Java, you can create a junit test suites and put all your junit test cases in it. This allows you to run all your test cases all at once and get the testing results immediately (e.g. how many tests passsed and failed, and which tests failed). Is there something equivalent in Scala within the ScalaTest?

Thanks

Comment: I spent some time looking for the same thing recently and what I came up with is just the idea of putting semantically related units (single tests) all inside a single class (e.g. the one extending FunSuite). In case you run tests from within sbt you'll definitely want them all to be run, and in case you are inside IDE (in my case, IDEA), you always have an option to run several classes simultaneously (as well as 'all tests in package' or 'all tests in `test`'). So that's how you deal with this things in Scala.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if there's anything equivalent for ScalaTest but in general this is a bad idea.  It requires you to keep your test suite class up to date when you add new tests.  Both your IDE and your build tool should let you be able to automatically discover and run all tests at once.

If you're using maven or gradle, just placing all your tests under the src/test/scala directory should be enough that running the `test` target will execute all test